# How to make dismissed dialog disappear

Tags: android, android-fragments, dismiss

I'm trying to use a custom dialog fragment to get some input from user and I've come across this problem. The dialog never dismisses, even when i use `getDialog.dismiss()` or `this.dismiss()` from the dialog class or even when i try to remove it with `fragmentTransaction.remove(fragment)` after having retrieved it with `getFragmentByTag`. Actually, i noticed that the dialog can no longer be accessed after dismiss but still doesn't disappear.

When i click OK to dismiss for the first time, the `OnClickListener` gets called inside fragment class and   `getDialog().dismiss();` is executed but i can still see the dialog. And when i click on it for the second time, i get an error saying that I'm trying to access a null reference so i understood that the object was destroyed but the fragment is still visible.

This is the error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.Dialog.dismiss()' on a null object reference
            at tg.androidgeek.ezna.Produits.AddProduitDialog$1.onClick(AddProduitDialog.java:75)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4764)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19844)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
```

Here is the fragment class :

```
    public class AddProduitDialog extends DialogFragment implements TextView.OnEditorActionListener/*, View.OnClickListener */{
    private static final String TAG = "AddProduitDialog";
    Button BtOkProduit;
    Button BtKoProduit;
    Spinner spinner;
    ArrayList<Categorie> Categories;
    private EditText mEditText;
    private EditText mEditTextPrix;

    public AddProduitDialog() {
        // Empty constructor required for DialogFragment
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_produit, container);

        //Getting All Categories from DataBase
        CategorieManager cm = new CategorieManager(getContext());
        cm.open();
        Categories = cm.getAllCategorieObjects();
        cm.close();

        spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_add_categorie);
        SpinAdapter spinAdapter = new SpinAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.item_row_spinner, Categories);
        spinner.setAdapter(spinAdapter);

        mEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText);
        mEditTextPrix = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_text_prix);
        getDialog().setTitle("Ajoutez Un Produit");

        // Show soft keyboard automatically
        mEditText.requestFocus();
        getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
        mEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(this);
        BtOkProduit = (Button) (view.findViewById(R.id.btnOkProduit));
        BtKoProduit = (Button) (view.findViewById(R.id.btnKoProduit));

        BtKoProduit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick btnKo");
                getDialog().dismiss();
               // if (AddProduitDialog.this!=null)AddProduitDialog.this.dismiss();
//Any other way I've tried fails 
            }
        });
       /* BtOkProduit.setOnClickListener(this);*/
        getDialog().cancel();
        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE == actionId) {
            // Return input text to activity
            EditProduitDialogListener activity = (EditProduitDialogListener) getActivity();
            Produit produit = new Produit(0,
                    mEditText.getText().toString(),
                    Categories.get(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()).getId()
                    , Double.parseDouble(mEditTextPrix.getText().toString())
                    , R.mipmap.ic_folder);

            activity.onFinishEditProduit(produit);
            this.dismiss();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }



    public interface EditProduitDialogListener {
        void onFinishEditProduit(Produit Value);
    }

    public class SpinAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Categorie> {
        ArrayList<Categorie> Values;
        Context context;

        public SpinAdapter(Context context, int RessoucreId, ArrayList<Categorie> Values) {
            super(context, RessoucreId, Values);
            this.Values = Values;
            this.context = context;
        }


        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            //  if (convertView == null) {
            TextView tv = (TextView) getLayoutInflater(null).inflate(R.layout.item_row_spinner, null);
            tv.setText(Values.get(position).getNom());
            return tv;
            // }
           /* TextView tv = (TextView) (convertView);
            tv.setText(Values.get(position).getNom());
            return tv;*/
        }

        @Override
        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (convertView == null) {
                TextView tv = (TextView) getLayoutInflater(null).inflate(R.layout.item_row_spinner, null);
                tv.setText(Values.get(position).getNom());
                return tv;
            }
            TextView tv = (TextView) (convertView);
            tv.setText(Values.get(position).getNom());
            return tv;
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the layout for the dialog

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/nom_du_produit"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:inputType="textShortMessage"
            android:lines="1"
            android:minWidth="100dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:text="@string/categorie"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner_add_categorie"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:text="@string/prix"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_text_prix"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:lines="1"
            android:linksClickable="false" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnOkProduit"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/ok" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnKoProduit"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/cancel" />
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

I really hope someone can help with this, Thank you.

Comment: you should be calling just dismiss

Comment: I tried that too. It made no difference. Thanks for the reply

Comment: where is your custom dialog class and why you used the getDialog/

Comment: AddProduitDialog is the custom dialog class and i used getDialog because dismiss(); did not work so i tried getDialog and it didn't work either.

Comment: how you are showing dialog?

Comment: I show it like this from mainActivity 
`new AddProduitDialog().show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "ProduitDialog");`

Comment: Try checking if the constructor for your dialog is getting called multiple times. I've been having the same issue and found that two dialog fragments are being created at nearly the same time, but you are only left with a handle to one. I think my issue is caused by  [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34515801/android-findfragmentbytag-returns-null-when-debugging)