# Android findFragmentByTag returns null when debugging

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-studio

**Background:**

I am writing an android application with an activity that can be populated by one of a number of fragments. Relatively often, I need to pass a bundle of data to the active fragment so that it can update the UI accordingly.

To get the current fragment, I call `getfragmentManager().findFragmentByTag()` and cast the returned fragment to my custom fragment class.

**The problem:**

The above method usually works fine. However, `findFragmentByTag()` occasionally returns null. Upon further investigation, I have concluded that this will only occur when I run or debug from Android studio (and even then it doesn't happen every time).

**Relevant Code:**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    //Do lots of stuff
    currentFragmentTag = "";
    getFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(
            new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
                public void onBackStackChanged() {
                    if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
                        currentFragmentTag = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() - 1).getName();
                    }

                }
            });
    init();

    //Do some more stuff

    //this should always be the case
    if (currentFragmentTag.equals(LOGIN_FRAGMENT_TAG)) {
        ((LoginFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(currentFragmentTag)).beginLogin();
    }

}


private void init(){
    //changed to reflect George Mulligan's advice
    Fragment currentFrag = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(LOGIN_FRAGMENT_TAG);
    if(currentFrag == null) {
        currentFragmentTag = LOGIN_FRAGMENT_TAG;
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, loginFrag, LOGIN_FRAGMENT_TAG)
                .addToBackStack(LOGIN_FRAGMENT_TAG)
                .commit();
        getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();

    }
}

public void updateFragment(){
    Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();
    //put stuff in dataBundle

    if (currentFragmentTag.equals(LOGIN_FRAGMENT_TAG)) {
        LoginFragment currentFrag = (LoginFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(currentFragmentTag);
        if (currentFrag != null) {
            currentFrag.passBundleToFragment(dataBundle);
            Log.d(TAG, "Fragment returned is valid.");
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Fragment returned is null.");
        }
    } 
    //else if a different fragment is active then update it in the same way
}

//Manually open the loginFragment. This can be called from other fragments. My problem always occurs before this is called however. 
@Override
public void openLoginScreen() {
    if(/*some conditions*/) {
        LoginFragment loginFrag = LoginFragment.newInstance();
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, loginFrag, LOGIN_FRAGMENT_TAG)
                .addToBackStack(LOGIN_FRAGMENT_TAG)
                .commit();
        getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
        currentFragmentTag = LOGIN_FRAGMENT_TAG;
        updateFragment();
    }
}
```

Normally, my logcat looks something like this:

```
Fragment returned is valid
Fragment returned is valid
Fragment returned is valid
Fragment returned is valid
Fragment returned is valid
Fragment returned is valid
Fragment returned is valid
Fragment returned is valid
...etc.
```

But every now and then, and only when I start the app from Android Studio, I get something like:

```
Fragment returned is valid
Fragment returned is valid
Fragment returned is valid
Fragment returned is valid
Fragment returned is null
Fragment returned is null
Fragment returned is null
Fragment returned is null
Fragment returned is null
Fragment returned is null
Fragment returned is null
Fragment returned is null
Fragment returned is null
Fragment returned is null
Fragment returned is valid
Fragment returned is valid
Fragment returned is valid
Fragment returned is valid
Fragment returned is valid
Fragment returned is valid
Fragment returned is valid
Fragment returned is valid
Fragment returned is valid
Fragment returned is null
Fragment returned is null
Fragment returned is null
Fragment returned is null
Fragment returned is null
Fragment returned is null
Fragment returned is null
Fragment returned is valid
Fragment returned is valid
```

What on Earth is going on here?

UPDATE:

I have been able to reproduce this error while disconnected from Android Studio by clicking the app switch button, closing my app and immediately restarting it. Provided I do this quickly enough, it never fails to behave as I described above.

After some more logging and chasing down other issues, I discovered that in these particular cases, `onCreate()` is being called twice.

My app is designed to run only in landscape mode, in part to avoid issues that come with recreating the activity. It would seem, however, that when the app is closed and restarted quickly, Android never finishes the necessary rotation to portrait mode for the home screen before my app is launched again. My assumption is that this causes the OS to rotate back to landscape after the app is running and thereby restart it.

All of this is fine and dandy, except for the fact that it doesn't explain why `findFragmentByTag()` sometimes returns null.

Every object in my Activity class should be recreated, right? So shouldn't the FragmentManager be re-initialized as well? Or is `getFragmentManager()` a static reference to something outside of the Activity itself?

SECOND UPDATE:

I tried George's idea of checking if the fragment had already been added before I call `beginTransaction()` and, although it didn't solve the problem, I noticed something strange when debugging:

I set a breakpoint at `Log.d(TAG, "Fragment returned is null.");`. Closing the app and quickly restarting it guarantees that this code will be reached as I mentioned above. Then, if I view the Fragment Manager by calling `getFragmentManager()` in the Evaluate Expression window, I notice that a `Login Fragment' has already been added, but it doesn't have a tag associated with it.

Setting a breakpoint at `Log.d(TAG, "Fragment returned is valid.");`in the same app session, however, reveals the `LoginFragment` is added with a tag as would be expected.

There is no point in my code where I ever add a fragment without setting a tag. Could this have something to do with the activity being recreated and the Fragment manager losing tags even though it holds onto the fragments themselves?

Comment: Based on your update are you overriding `onSaveInstanceState` in your activity? If so make sure you are calling `super.onSaveInstanceState`. I believe that is where the fragment state is saved.

Comment: I am not overriding `onSaveInsanceState`

Comment: Very odd. Can you post a simplified version of your activity and fragment that reproduces the problem? It must be something simple somewhere...I cannot think of what might cause the Fragment to lose its tag outside of doing something wrong with the fragment manager or fragment itself.

Comment: It's odd indeed. This is not an answer to your problem, but what about using `findFragmentById(R.id.container)` instead? This will return you a Fragment that's currently attached to your `R.id.container` view, so you can even get rid of a `currentFragmentTag` variable.

Comment: Also, what is your `compiledSdkVersion` just to be sure it is not dependent on that?

Comment: @GeorgeMulligan I added what I believe to be every bit of code that deals with the FragmentManager before the issue occurs. Also, my `compiledSdkVersion` is 21

Comment: Try `child fragment manager` instead of fragment manager

Comment: @MsYvette `updateFragment()` is called in a number of asynchronous callbacks such on gps location change or when certain sensor events occur

Comment: @JohannB did you ever work out a fix for this? Having a similar issue of fragments returning `null` intermittently. Annoyingly for me it's only from users in the field & cannot reproduce locally

Answer (score 8):

A few things to note on this.
In `updateFragment` you should really compare your Strings using `.equals` instead of reference comparison `==` so `LOGIN_FRAGMENT_TAG.equals(currentFragmentTag)`as a best practice and to avoid confusion.

Also, the `FragmentManager` will remember which fragments you have added to it across orientation changes. So in the one example you mentioned where you get into `onCreate` twice you will then likely have two instances of your `LoginFrag` on the back stack.

You can avoid this by doing the same lookup you are doing in your `updateFragment` method and only adding the fragment if it isn't found.

```
LoginFragment currentFrag = (LoginFragment) getFragmentManager()
    .findFragmentByTag(LOGIN_FRAGMENT_TAG);

if(currentFrag == null) {
    currentFrag = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.container, loginFrag, LOGIN_FRAGMENT_TAG)
        .addToBackStack(LOGIN_FRAGMENT_TAG)
        .commit();

    //executePendingTransactions() usually isn't necessary...
    getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
}
```

I'm guessing multiple fragments are used in this activity since you bother having the String `currentFragmentTag` but if not then it would be better for you to just keep a reference to your `LoginFragment` as a field on the class so you can avoid the additional lookup of it in the `updateFragment` method.

Other than that I tried reproducing your error and I cannot so the error might be elsewhere in code you are not showing.

Comment: Good call on the strings. And you're right in assuming I'm using multiple fragments. I added the null check before `beginTransaction` as you suggested. It didn't fix my issue, but I noticed something strange when I did. See my update

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a direct answer to your question, but a suggestion for avoiding the problem in the first place.

Because the interaction between the Fragment and Activity Lifecycles is so complex and difficult to reason about, I've found that it's much easier if you completely decouple the two.

Instead of obtaining a reference to the Fragment and invoking a method on it directly, I set up a message bus (e.g. Otto or GreenRobot) and in your case, would have the Activity post a message to the bus, and have the Fragment subscribe to that message. Much cleaner, and if the Fragment happens to not be ready (hasn't registered with the bus yet), there's no error condition.

Comment: Interesting idea. Reworking the code to use a bus like that however would require a fair bit of work (and time). But If nothing else works this is something I will consider

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this should be a comment but, code formatting is ugly as a comment. Perhaps your fragment gets paused.
try this

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    updateFragment();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem is that I need to call 'updateFragment()' often (whenever gps location changes for instance). So I can't really predict exactly when it will be called. What gets me is the fact that this only happens when I run from Android Studio